# How to Loop through JSON response text and get all values usingPHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
{
"ver":1,
"inputs":[
  {
     "sequence":4294967295,
     "witness":"",
     "prev_out":{
        "spent":true,
        "tx_index":372805487,
        "type":0,
        "addr":"3AFgA1pHKrk4jFHwzUL1CKgZvXyFSWZfgD",
        "value":12712,
        "n":0,
        "script":"a9145dee3b52c0c363fd962c57f33f346c453dba7e5687"
     },
     "script":"00483045022100a3edd460e3aa186f4b318930d80ca97cb25d5e741896cf0a396151c0b0e39953022012f0bad5edea4aca199e19c68859e3f04a4dc7bedd5ceecfdba652707490e1bf0147304402206b86cf8f21dc79d85a1ba341416cabf98b1c837fa3468c5cec4ad0d2f707fe2f02205da8b6ffe1ec67bf703a4f1a45394c4f9ac7c14db2216d937025fdcb0dfe007501475221031131d02767e849cc0a03d067569b77a3b0b28797d1fecacfeaee6fa35a0634f221034b79ba896e312200d17e6a0e11266247522e48a6900a035231aca2c596dcc20e52ae"
  }
],
"weight":1212,
"block_height":543349,
"relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
"out":[
  {
     "spent":false,
     "tx_index":377146538,
     "type":0,
     "addr":"13Zggf2Jc8K6e2hZ9fTP8ymzVyaYQWhRBR",
     "value":5443,
     "n":0,
     "script":"76a9141c1eb04aeb07c5a80fff5d7ab6382f6550dccd3188ac"
  }
],
"lock_time":0,
"size":303,
"double_spend":false,
"time":1538084433,
"tx_index":377146538,
"vin_sz":1,
"hash":"249256b255e9850fbf9abcbc73f8c872be2b51d3a055b66680bc7150f5bc1d1e",
"vout_sz":1
}
```

Comment: `$array = json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Comment: All values of what? Just every value of every key? Only certain keys? Or are you specifically talking about the "value" key? And what are you trying to do with them? Output them? Collect them in an array? Can you add some text to your question to clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert json response to php array using `json_decode`.

snippet

```
$json = '{
"ver":1,
"inputs":[
  {
     "sequence":4294967295,
     "witness":"",
     "prev_out":{
        "spent":true,
        "tx_index":372805487,
        "type":0,
        "addr":"3AFgA1pHKrk4jFHwzUL1CKgZvXyFSWZfgD",
        "value":12712,
        "n":0,
        "script":"a9145dee3b52c0c363fd962c57f33f346c453dba7e5687"
     },
     "script":"00483045022100a3edd460e3aa186f4b318930d80ca97cb25d5e741896cf0a396151c0b0e39953022012f0bad5edea4aca199e19c68859e3f04a4dc7bedd5ceecfdba652707490e1bf0147304402206b86cf8f21dc79d85a1ba341416cabf98b1c837fa3468c5cec4ad0d2f707fe2f02205da8b6ffe1ec67bf703a4f1a45394c4f9ac7c14db2216d937025fdcb0dfe007501475221031131d02767e849cc0a03d067569b77a3b0b28797d1fecacfeaee6fa35a0634f221034b79ba896e312200d17e6a0e11266247522e48a6900a035231aca2c596dcc20e52ae"
  }
],
"weight":1212,
"block_height":543349,
"relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
"out":[
  {
     "spent":false,
     "tx_index":377146538,
     "type":0,
     "addr":"13Zggf2Jc8K6e2hZ9fTP8ymzVyaYQWhRBR",
     "value":5443,
     "n":0,
     "script":"76a9141c1eb04aeb07c5a80fff5d7ab6382f6550dccd3188ac"
  }
],
"lock_time":0,
"size":303,
"double_spend":false,
"time":1538084433,
"tx_index":377146538,
"vin_sz":1,
"hash":"249256b255e9850fbf9abcbc73f8c872be2b51d3a055b66680bc7150f5bc1d1e",
"vout_sz":1
}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true); // you can use $arr direct as json hierarchy

//or convert to one-dimensional array
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($item, $key) use (&$result){
    $result[$key] = $item;
});
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [ver] => 1
    [sequence] => 4294967295
    [witness] => 
    [spent] => 
    [tx_index] => 377146538
    [type] => 0
    [addr] => 13Zggf2Jc8K6e2hZ9fTP8ymzVyaYQWhRBR
    [value] => 5443
    [n] => 0
    [script] => 76a9141c1eb04aeb07c5a80fff5d7ab6382f6550dccd3188ac
    [weight] => 1212
    [block_height] => 543349
    [relayed_by] => 0.0.0.0
    [lock_time] => 0
    [size] => 303
    [double_spend] => 
    [time] => 1538084433
    [vin_sz] => 1
    [hash] => 249256b255e9850fbf9abcbc73f8c872be2b51d3a055b66680bc7150f5bc1d1e
    [vout_sz] => 1
)
```

Live [Demo](https://3v4l.org/9eRS5)

**Please Note:** You can use `$arr` as json hierarchy or you can convert all key and value to one-dimensional array.

> Warning: Duplicate keys will be overwritten

**Docs**

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

[array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)